# Why does the Logic App (consumption) for a Service Bus topic trigger take so long to fire?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, servicebus

I am using an Azure Logic App that is triggered when a message is received on a Service Bus topic. Even though I set the trigger frequency to check 10 times every minute, it is taking much longer (10 minutes). Do you know why?

[image]

It is a consumption Logic App. I do not see anything in the logs to suggest I am being Throttled.

1. There are very few messages to process. Only one.
2. Workflow is not complex.
3. I have confirmed that the message is in the topic subscription waiting to be picked up.

I believe I would not have these problems if I choose standard instead of consumption.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK , I have used Standard Logic App and I get expected results, i.e when message is received in Service bus topic I get triggered correctly by using as below:

[image]

In consumption plan one property you can use  `How often do you want to check for items?` condition as below but in Standard we can't use it:

[image]